# save order to database before goto paypal page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using paypal express checkout at my site. In the checkout page. I want to save the order into database when customers click the conform order button in the step 6. Can someone help me?  Many thanks...

Comment: I found that the order info has been stored in database when I confirmed the order in checkout page. Due to some unknown reason I cannot see the order info at admin page....

Comment: The order was marked as missing order, now I can find the order at the admin backend.

Comment: Every confirmed order is saved into the database. The reason it's not showing in the Sale / Orders section, because the order hasn't been paid for, so Opencart considers it as a Missing Order. If you change the Status on the Sale / Orders screen to "Missing Orders", then it will show all the missing orders that your customers have placed, but haven't actually paid for. I would not recommend you to process any of these orders, unless you want to give stuff away for free.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the order status indicator is not changed until you get a response back from PayPal indicating that the order has been successfully processed. Your server may be rejecting the response due to some WAF settings or other other reason. This is of course, assuming that you have confirmed payment on the PayPal side and the order is still showing in your OC admin as a missing order.

Speak with your server admins to inspect the network traffic and determine if the PayPal response is being blocked. If not, then you may need to look into the Express Checkout settings in OC admin and set the order status associated with a successfully-processed order. It will obviously need to be different from "missing order", though may be the default option if "missing order" is your default order status.